# Can I remotely change configuration of applications monitored by MS Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have very little experience with application insights, except for the "hello world" programs I have put together, created a few custom events, forwarded messages from log4net.

As I am beginning to add this into more applications I am wondering "Can I remotely turn on more detailed logging information, in an ad-hoc fashion?"  More specificly I would like to have App Insights doing what it normally does and continue to log exceptions, requests, and what not....but on particularly busy times I would like to enable more of a "performance monitoring" aspect for a couple of hours, but without having to deploy a new version of the application to everyone.

I haven't seen anything online that speaks about something close to this, but I also may not know the appropriate keywords to look for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have enabled App Insights in the package. There's no other way... but as a workaround:

You should publish the site and an additional deployment slot with fewer resources (to reduce costs). Every time you update your solution you should deploy it to production and the "other slot".

When you need to "**turn on**" App insights just swipe between "other slot" and "production slot" , get all data you have and then when you don't need insights anymore swipe again between them.

You can also shutdown the deployment slot and just power it on when you need to make the magic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This is perhaps one way to accomplish something very similar if I was using websites hosted in azure.

Answer (score 0):

What other data would you like to see registered? Right now, all configuration for telemetry capture in Application Insights is directly related to what telemetry modules and context initializers you have configured in ApplicationInsights.config, and there's really no way to dynamically add more to that.

However, nothing prevents you from manually adding additional custom events through the use of TelemetryClient directly, and you could certainly control the code that calls this through other means.

Can you maybe expand on what other kind of data you'd like to see captured?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Telemetry Channel (http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/09/03/more-telemetry-channels/) that will filter out (or not) some non-critical telemetry based on some state/flag. Or you can have two telemetry channels (one standard and one custom) and swap them based on flag.

Better yet, you can consider using the new extensibility point, called Telemetry Processor - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/request-filtering-in-application-insights-with-telemetry-processor/ to do the same

Then you can implement a remote call to your app (e.g. have a special URL) that will change this flag.